# Edited hosts file but cannot still not resolving URL. I can access just using the IP

Tags: windows, dns, ip

I am trying to access `test.sample.local` but pc cannot resolve the URL. I added the URL-IP to `etc/hosts` file but still cannot access it.

I can access destination with the IP.

The computer is Windows 8.1 and I am entering the following in the `hosts` file:

```
test.sample.local 176.235.11.11
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to access in local machine or remote machine.

Comment: etc/hosts? What OS are you using?

Comment: @Darius Windows 8.1

Comment: @vembutech local machine

Comment: What *exactly* are you putting in `etc/hosts`?

Comment: @Mokubai test.sample.local  176.235.11.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format for the Windows hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`) is

```
127.0.0.1       myWebsite.com
```

Rather than what you claim to have entered:

```
test.sample.local 176.235.11.11
```

So swap it around to

```
176.235.11.11    test.sample.local
```

Which should help.

For more information (and a helpful tool to do the editing for you) see
[TheWindowsClub: Windows hosts file](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/hosts-file-in-windows).